# Trying to reverse the sequence of values returned by my gcloud query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a gcloud query that performs a certain task and returns a table of values exported to a CSV file.

There is one particular field that returns multiple values within each cell of its column. For example: `Item1,Item2,Item3,...,ItemN`

I would like to reverse this sequence.

Desired output: `ItemN,...,Item3,Item2,Item1`

Now I know that I can use Bash to do this. But I think that there's a *sort()* option in gcloud as well, something like `--format="csv(FieldName.sort())"`.

Can someone please help me here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please include more details in your question to help us answer it.

There's a projection function [`sort`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections#sort) that may help.

Compute Engine instances are a good exemplar as they contain repeating properties ([labels](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get#body.Instance.FIELDS.labels), [scopes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get#body.Instance.FIELDS.inlinedField_97)) and these values can be sorted using `sort()`:

```sh
PROJECT=...
ZONE=...

# sort: labels (keys)
gcloud compute instances describe ${INSTANCE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--format="value(labels.sort())"

# sort: 1st associated Service Account's scopes
gcloud compute instances describe ${INSTANCE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--format="value(serviceAccounts[0].scopes.sort())"
```

Comment: How do I reverse the sequence of values using the _sort()_ function?

Comment: I don't mean descending order (Z to A). I mean literally reverse the sequence, just as I've described in my question. What attribute should I pass inside the _sort()_ function?

Comment: Aha! I misread. If the value is a list, then you can use `.slice(: :-1)` to effectively reverse it

Comment: The slice() function is not giving the intended result. Let's say a cell value is "Red, Green, Yellow" and my desired output is "Yellow, Green, Red". What do I use? Thanks.

Comment: Please include a specific example. It would be useful, but I think there's no way for me to provide you an arbitrary example of formatting; I can only show you with an actual example as I've been doing. In the case of `gcloud compute instances describe`, the format that reverses the order of the list of scopes is: `gcloud compute instances describe instance-1 --zone=${ZONE} --project=${PROJECT} --format="value(serviceAccounts[0].scopes.slice(: :-1))"`

Comment: Understood, thanks.